# JavaScript: issue calling remove() function from button's onclick event

Tags: javascript, onclick

The following code works fine in IE8, but doesn't work in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

The [Remove] button calls a remove() function that is declared at the top of the page.  When I click the button in Chrome or Firefox, the button is removed from the page.  When I click the button in IE8, it works fine.  When I rename the remove() function to something like removeIt(), it works in all browsers.

Does anyone have an explanation as to what could be causing this behavior?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function remove( form, path)
{
    alert ('inside remove');
   form.action = "/storefrontCommerce" + path;
   form.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="itemListForm" onsubmit="setAction(itemDetailForm, 'cartAddItems.do')" action="/storefrontCommerce/itemDetail.do" method="post" name="itemDetailForm"></form>

<input class="button" type="button" value="Remove " onclick="remove(itemDetailForm, '/shoppinglistRemoveItem.do')">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: DOM4 includes a `remove()` method on elements - IE8 doesn't support it, but recent Chrome, Firefox, etc. do (see [Removing an element with the plain JavaScript remove() method](http://red-team-design.com/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/)).  You're calling `remove()` in the context of the clicked button, so that *button's* `remove()` method gets called instead of your global `remove()`.

Comment: Interesting.  But my global remove() has two parameters.  Does the DOM4 remove() also include two parameters?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Javascript calls are by name and scope, with no overloading based on parameters.